# Three days through/in the wilderness: to where?

Tags: yetziat-mitzrayim, va-eira, parashas-shemos

In shemot 3:18 Adonai commands Moshe to tell the King of Egypt: 'nelacha-na derech shloshet yamim bamidbar venizbecha laHaShem Eloheinu'-'let us go a journey of three days into the wilderness, to sacrifice before HaShem our G-d'.Shemot 5:3 describes this event, but Pharoh refuses to let them go. This is why Moshe repeats this message in 8:23.

**Question to what was this three day journey (a way of three yamim long) refering to? (to which place or event?)**

side notes:

After Pharoh let them go, the splitting of the Yam Suf etc. they arrive at the wilderniss, trafel for three days and arrive at Marah (Bamidbar 33:8).

Yom could also refer to a time period and the verse of 19:1 reads: BaChodesh Hashlishi.. after three months they arrived at the Midbar Sinai.

Pesach: the lamb kept for three days..

Comment: You're assuming that it refers to an event that actually occurred, but according to most commentators, the 'event' was either planned, but didn't occur until much later (the event being "serving God on this mountain", 3:12, which actually took place in ch. 24) or that there was never supposed to be such an event anyway, and this was just a way to trick the Egyptians and steal their stuff (3:22, 12:35)

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50491/was-moshe-decieving-pharoh-or-was-the-original-exodus-from-egypt-meant-to-be/50552#50552

Comment: This is similar to a question asked last week. One key issue in asking for just 3 days leave was to show it was a reasonable request and how excessively stubborn and cruel Pharoah was

Comment: http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemot/3.18#e0n6 see Hakesav Vehakkabalah, Chizkuni, RDZ Hoffman, among others.  Someone else is welcome to write it up as an answer...